# $f\in PC(2\pi)$ is such that $f'\in PC(2\pi)$. Then the Fourier series of $f$ converges uniformly absolutely to a continous function $g$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Suppose that $f\in PC(2\pi)$ is such that $f'\in PC(2\pi)$ (if $f\in PC(2\pi)$ then $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)dx=\int_c^{c+2\pi}f(x)dx \quad\forall c\in\mathbb{R}$). Then the Fourier series  of $f$ converges uniformly absolutely to a continous function $g$.

My try:

I know that the coefficients of the Fourier series of $f$ can be written in terms of $f'$ Fourier coeficients. This is:  $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}/\{0\}$, $a_n(f)=-\frac{b_n(f')}{n}\quad$ and
$\quad b_n(f)=\frac{a_n(f')}{n}$.

$$S_n(f)(x)=\frac{a_0(f)}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left[a_k(f) cos(kx)+b_k(f) sin(kx) \right]$$
$$= \frac{a_0(f)}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left[-\frac{b_k(f') cos(kx)}{k}+\frac{a_k(f') sin(kx)}{k}  \right]$$
$$= \frac{a_0(f)}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left[\frac{a_k(f') sin(kx)}{k}-\frac{b_k(f') cos(kx)}{k} \right]$$

I'm not sure on how to prove that this series converges. I only know that by the Riemann Lebesgue Lemma the values of the series are zero when $n$ goes to infinity. Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Show that $\sum a_k(f')^2+b_k(f')^2$ finite by parseval and integrability of $f'$ and then apply the AG inequality $|2a_k(f)| \leq b_k(f')^2+1/k^2$ and same for $|b_k(f)|$ to show absolute convergence

Comment: "I'm not sure on how to prove that this series converges." convergence of _that_ series is more or less irrelevant. What does "converges absolutely" mean?